Filter according the content of a field
I have the following input json:
INPUT
{
  "temp": "1010328|1010329",
  "data": [
    {
      "product": {
        "items": [
          {
            "item_number": "1010328",
            "attributes": [
              {
                "id": "myId01",
                "type": "int"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "item_number": "1010329",
            "attributes": [
              {
                "id": "myId02",
                "type": "int"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "item_number": "1010330",
            "attributes": [
              {
                "id": "myId03",
                "type": "int"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

within the items array , the items should be filtered according to the value of "temp":
DESIRED OUTPUT
{
  "temp": "1010328|1010329",
  "data": [
    {
      "product": {
        "items": [
          {
            "item_number": "1010328",
            "attributes": [
              {
                "id": "myId01",
                "type": "int"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "item_number": "1010329",
            "attributes": [
              {
                "id": "myId02",
                "type": "int"
              }
            ]
          }
         
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

I tried to do a normal filtering in jolt with the string 1010328|1010329 assigned to a nifi variable "temp". But apparently jolt does not accept the value of variables, when it comes to "filter-tasks".

You can start with converting "temp" attribute to an array, loop under the indexes of the array and reform back to its original structure as in the following transformation :
[
  { //convert "temp" attribute to an array with the identical name
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "temp": "=split('\\|',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "temp": "&",
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "product": {
            "items": {
              "*": {
                "*": "@(1,item_number).&5.&4.&3.&2.&" //keep the all nestine key names
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "temp": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@(3,&)": ""
          }
        },
        "@": "&" //keep the "temp" array
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "temp": "&",
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&3[&2].&1.&[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //convert "temp" back to an attribute
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "temp": "=join('|',@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site Jolt Transform Demo Using v0.1.1 is ( just tweaked the "temp" ) :

